# variable output form foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, variables, for-loop, return

I have this sample code from a lastfm script i found..:

```
function getArtistAlbums($artist, $size) {
    $artist = urlencode($artist);
    $xml    = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist={$artist}&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $xml    = @file_get_contents($xml);

    if(!$xml) {
        return;  // Artist lookup failed.
    }

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $xml = $xml->topalbums;
    foreach ($xml->album as $album) {
        $album_img =  $album->image[$size];
        $album_image = convert($album_img);
        $album_name =  $album->name;

        //echo instead of returning
        echo $album_name."<br>".$album_image."<br><br>";
    }
```

but instead of echoing the results I want to return all `$album_image` to a variable and call it from another file. I tried this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$xml = $xml->topalbums;
$values = array();
foreach ($xml->album as $album) {
    $album_img =  $album->image[$size];
    $album_image = convert($album_img);
    $album_name =  $album->name;
    $values[] = $album_image;
    return $values;

    //echo instead of returning                     
    #echo $album_name."<br>".$album_image."<br><br>";
}
```

I know I need to build an array. I tried different things but I always get "Array" when I call the variable.

The script is from here: http://techslides.com/lastfm-api-with-php/. In my other PHP script when I call the other functions, for example artist-album, I get a return with an image and then I can style it and output what I want. But I can't figure out how to output the above. When I call it inside an

```
echo '<div class='example'>'.getArtistAlbums(artist,2).'</div>';
```

it just echoes images.

The question is how can I somehow return variables and then use inside another variable as a did for example for artist-album. For example:

```
$artist_image = getArtist($artist,2);
```

and then use `$artist_image` with `echo` and `clas`s etc.

Comment: `echo`ing an array will show `Array`. If you want to inspect the content of the array, you have to use `print_r` or `var_dump`. I don't see a point in returning inside the loop though. It will terminate the function after the first iteration.

Comment: What does the other file look like???
Of course it would be an array, because it is an array.
Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Kylek i just updated the post with the link to original script and what i'm trying to do.. Thanks for replying :)

Comment: Using proper punctuation, grammar and formatting makes your question easier to read and understand. Regarding the edit, when you return an array, you have to *iterate* over that array as well (just like you did inside the function) and style each item individually. KyleK shows exactly that in his answer (only that they directly `echo` the value instead of adding HTML to it).

Comment: I don't understand what youre trying to do....from what I get, you're trying to take an output from one function an dinput to another?

Comment: Are you meaning you wanna apply formatting to each image, instead of just echoing all the images into that one div?

Comment: Check my update, I think I got what you want :)

Comment: I will try it and let u know... Sorry for the messy formating :) I actually want to put all the images output of `getArtistAlbum($artist,2);` inside a div, previously with the echo even when i call the function inside the div results was always out of the div..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$xml = $xml->topalbums;
$values = array();
foreach ($xml->album as $album) {
    $album_img =  $album->image[$size];
    $album_image = convert($album_img);
    $album_name =  $album->name;
    array_push($values, $album_image);
}
return $values;
```

Check to make sure everything inside the array is correct:

```
var_dump($values);
```

To access the values in the other file..

```
foreach($values as $val){
    echo $val;
}
```

**EDIT...I think this is what youre trying to do...**

```
$values = getArtistAlbum(artist, 2);

foreach($values as $val){
    echo "<div class='example'>".$val."</div>";
}
```

Once you have executed the getArtistAlbum function, you get the array returned to you...which you can then iterate over and display accordingly.

You can also skip the step of doing two loops, and just integrate the div build into the getArtistAlbum function itself...like so....but the other way is better, since it produces more reuseable code

```
function getArtistAlbum($artist, $size){
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $xml = $xml->topalbums;

    foreach ($xml->album as $album) {
        $album_img =  $album->image[$size];
        $album_image = convert($album_img);
        $album_name =  $album->name;
        echo "<div class='example'>".$album_image."</div>
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2 (based on your comments)**

For one div...

```
$values = getArtistAlbum(artist, 2);

echo "<div class='example'>";
foreach($values as $val){
    echo $val;
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Ah, that was the only change you had when I made my comment so I was wondering what the point is ;)

Comment: Maybe you could add `$values = getArtistAlbums($artist, $size);` to your answer, just to make sure the OP understands what `$values` is and where it comes from.

Comment: I really dont understand why I got downvoted, this answer is exactly what the OP is wanting...

Comment: @Kylek it didn't work.. my code is a lot messy and i have to review all the php.. As vardump it works fine, i can see output , but when i call `$values = getArtistAlbum(artist, 2);` at the same line a call for the other images (artist for ex) in the other php file, it just outputs zero results.. if i move the call on the end of the php file after all other calls it outputs the vardump. PS i didnt downvoted u.

Comment: @Kylek i manage to get it working but i want all the images inside the same div, now all images have their own div.. Any idea would be great :)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 $album_name='';

    foreach ($xml->album as $album) {
                        $album_img =  $album->image[$size];
                        $album_image = convert($album_img);
                        $album_name =  $album->name;
                        $values[] = $album_image;
                        return $values;

                        //echo instead of returning

                       $album_name.=$album_image;


                }

    echo $album_name;
```

Comment: `$album_name.=.$album_image;` and `echo $album_name;` won't be executed. Did you intend to remove the `return` statement?